# How can I change all references in a column from absolute to relative excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, reference

I have an excel file with multiple columns and 200 rows. Each cell has an absolute reference to another sheet. How can change all the references from absolute to relative ? So that I can add new columns by dragging the values from existing columns.

Comment: You can do a search and replace (Search in formulas) to swap `$` to "". Assumes there are no other instances of `$` inside any of the formulas (as inputs or strings)

Comment: Select cells you have formula the hit `F4` to change reference type from absolute to relative or relative to absolute.